# Is there way to use rapidjson with std::string efficiently?

Tags: c++, string, rapidjson

I'm trying to work with rapidjson.

I want to generate string and add it to some `rapidjson::Value` which is object.

I was using std::string when worked with qjson, but in case of rapidjson it seems inappropriate. I don't want to generate string and then copy it, string object lifetime ends before object (`rapidjson::Value`) lifetime (therefore `generated_string.c_str()` is not a case).
There may be \0 in json, so, `char*` with null-terminated string also not a solution.

So, I must write my own string type? Or use something like

```
auto create_string_object() -> rapidjson::GenericStringRef<char>
{
   size_t len;
   char* result;
    // generate char* result with length len
   const char* return_value = result;
   return rapidjson::StringRef(return_value,len);
}
auto create_object_object(rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType &allocator) -> rapidjson::Value
{
   // ...
   rapidjson::Value result(rapidjson::kObjectType);
   rapidjson::Value tmp;  // tmp = create_string_object() will not compile
   tmp = create_string_object();
   result.AddMember("key", tmp, allocator); 
   // ...
}
```

Or there are some other ways to work with strings? It seems hard to me. We can't move string to `rapidjson::Value` because of different structures inside that `Value`, we can't set pointer inside `Value` to `c_str()` because string will be destroyed before `Value`.
Even with `GenericStringRef<char>` I must rewrite almost all work with strings.

By the way, why `RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING` is 0 by default? Some problems with work? I see that i can copy string into `rapidjson::Value` and copy pointer if I know that string lifetime will end before value lifetime.

**UPD:** Now I see that rapidjson frees only strings that were copied:

```
  //! Destructor.
  /*! Need to destruct elements of array, members of object, or copy-string.
  */
  ~GenericValue() {
      if (Allocator::kNeedFree) { // Shortcut by Allocator's trait
          switch(flags_) {
          case kArrayFlag:
              for (GenericValue* v = data_.a.elements; v != data_.a.elements + data_.a.size; ++v)
                  v->~GenericValue();
              Allocator::Free(data_.a.elements);
              break;

          case kObjectFlag:
              for (MemberIterator m = MemberBegin(); m != MemberEnd(); ++m)
                m->~Member();
              Allocator::Free(data_.o.members);
              break;

          case kCopyStringFlag:
              Allocator::Free(const_cast<Ch*>(data_.s.str));
              break;

          default:
              break;  // Do nothing for other types.
          }
      }
  }
```

So, as it was said in answer, using `GenericStringRef` in a way such as in my code here is a bad idea, because in such case I must manage memory by myself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do not completely understand the question. But I try to clarify a few things here.

1. `GenericStringRef` is used for preventing string copy. It should only be used if the string's lifetime is known to be sufficient. For string dynamically created, normally you should not use `GenericStringRef`.
2. Setting `RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING=1` is fine. It is not turned on by default because its support is added after early release. And I don't want RapidJSON header to include `<string>` if the user don't need to. Since you use `std::string`, you can turn it on. It should make you easier to deal with `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks. 
Sorry, after some time of thinking I realized that it's bad question: if I want always work with ```std::string``` (and ```rapidjson```), I must copy strings in some cases, if I want to avoid copying I must use ```char*``` or some types from ```rapidjson```, like in question.

Answer (score 0):

We can create GenericStringRef as `rapidjson::GenericStringRef{key.c_str()}`

I was was struggling with a simiar problem. I had to add a new field "id" to a document created out of json string. Below code worked for me.

```
std::string key=...;  // normal string as id
std::string value=...; // json string

rapidjson::Document record;
record.Parse(value.c_str());
rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType &allocator = record.GetAllocator();
rapidjson::Value id_value(key.c_str(), key.size(), allocator);
doc.AddMember("id", id_value, allocator);
```